# SQLAlchemy - Return filtered table AND corresponding foreign table values

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy mapped classes:

```
class ShowModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shows'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))    
    episodes = db.relationship('EpisodeModel', backref='episode', lazy='dynamic')

class EpisodeModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'episodes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shows.id'))
    info = db.relationship('InfoModel', backref='episode', lazy='dynamic')

class InfoModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'info'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    episode_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('episodes.id'))
```

I'm trying and failing to figure out how to perform a query that searches the `info` table for a specific `name` column value AND then return the `shows` and `episodes` table rows that are associated with it.

Using the following query allows me to return the specific `info` row that matches the `filter_by(name=name)` query

```
InfoModel.query.filter_by(name=name).all()))
```

But I am really struggling to figure out how to also get the values of the corresponding foreign key rows that have a relationship with the specific `info` row. Is there a proper way to do this with the join statement or something similar? Thank you very much for any help on this, as I'm still trying to get the hang of working with SQL databases, and databases in general.

Edit -

If, for example, I use the query `InfoModel.query.filter_by(name="ShowName1").all()))`, my json() representation returns

```
{
    "name": "InfoName1",
    "id": 1,
    "episode_id": 1
}
```

But I'm also wanting to return the associated foreign table values so that my json() representation returns -

```
{
    "name": "ShowName1",
    "id": 1,
    "episodes": 
    {
        "name": "EpisodeName1",
        "id": 1,
        "show_id": 1        
        "info": 
        {
            "name": "InfoName1",
            "id": 1,
            "episode_id": 1
        }
    },
}
```

And I apologize for fumbling over my use of jargon here, making my question appear more complicated than it is.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the query to return? Like, which rows from EpisodeModel and ShowModel are supposed to be returned?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you need lazyload set to dynamic as opposed to joined? Joined might get you what you want.

Comment: I edited the post to hopefully better explain what I'm trying to return. And I'm embarrassed to say that I'm not 100 percent sure why I have lazyload set to dynamic instead of joined, and now that you mention it, I'll be diligently studying the differences between the two. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have lazy loading enabled, the joined tables will only be set when they are accessed. What you can do is force a join. Something like the following should work for you:

```
shows = session.query(ShowModel)
               .join(EpisodeModel)
               .join(InfoModel)
               .filter(ShowModel.name == "foo")
               .all()
```

You can also change your load configuration to be "eager", or any number of other options. I don't like to do this by default though, as it makes for accidentally expensive queries: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html